# Editing datetime fields in MySQL using Delphi and firedac

Tags: mysql, delphi, firedac

I am using Delphi 10.1 and Firedac components to connect to a MySQL database. Using live bindings or the VCL data aware components I can edit the data in the MySQL tables except for dates (e.g. invoice date). I understand there is a type difference between the Delphi TDateTime and MySQL DateTime in ISO format but I can't work out how or where to undertake a conversion? Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a data type mapping for the `TFDConnection` mapping `dtTimeStamp` into `dtDateTime`. Something like:

```
with FDConnection1.FormatOptions.MapRules.Add do begin
  SourceDataType := dtTimeStamp;
  TargetDataType := dtDateTime;
end;
```